# Using LED's to track the sun with ESP32 analog inputs

Tags: arduino, led, esp32

I am trying to automate single-axis tracking of the sun for solar panels on my RV. I have a 10mm LED mounted on each side such that if the panel is aimed directly at the sun, both LED's get full sunlight. As the sun moves, one will become shaded. With my multimeter, I get ~0.5VDC shaded and ~2.0VDC in full sunlight. For an Arduino or similar as a controller, this should be perfect.

However, I'm not getting valid values with the LED's connected to the ESP32. Putting an LED in the shade changes my analogRead() value very little. I am getting around 1,600 - 2,000 shaded or not.

```
const int analogPin36 = 36;
const int analogPin39 = 39;
int analogPin36val = 0;
int analogPin39val = 0;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);

  pinMode(analogPin36,INPUT);
  pinMode(analogPin39,INPUT);
  int res = adcAttachPin(analogPin36);
  res = adcAttachPin(analogPin39);
}

void loop() {
  analogPin36val = analogRead(analogPin36);
  delay(500);
  analogPin39val = analogRead(analogPin39);
  delay(500);
  Serial.print("\t36: " + String(analogPin36val));
  Serial.println("\t39: " + String(analogPin39val));
}
```

If I connect my multimeter to an LED while it is **also** connected to the ESP32, I do not get a full voltage reading. This leads me to believe the LEDs are not putting out enough amperage to drive both the meter and the analog input. Additionally, I'm wondering if there is simply not enough power to reliably drive the ESP32 analog inputs.

I could parallel more LEDs or swap the LEDs for tiny solar panels to increase power but I'd rather build an amp that ups the power without increasing voltage above the 3.3 limit of the ESP32.

Two hours later, it's dark outside. To my surprise, I'm still getting readings from the ESP32 so I put the voltmeter on. 0.2vdc. How can this be? I disconnect to check just the LED and 0.0vdc. I connect to the analog port and I get 0.2vdc. I've set the ports as INPUT. So confused... Why do I have any voltage on an analog input port?

I see elsewhere that many recommend using a photoresistor or LDR. This is not an option as they go bad after being in direct sunlight for a while.

UPDATE: Thanks to @Mattman944 I've figured it out. The issue is that the LEDs are not able to drive the ADC. In other words, the input resistance of the ADCs is too low for the LEDs The solution is to add a unity gain buffer between the LED and ADC. I've completed the circuit and bench tested it. Now to get it installed and write the code so it intelligently aims the panels.

Comment: what color LED housing (plastic part) are you using? ... have you considered using two solar panels? ... rip up a couple of cheap solar garden lights

Comment: Do you really mean "LED"? I know that they generate a signal under illumination, I'm just asking because you didn't mention "photodiodes" at all...

Comment: Pinhole and 4-quadrant detector. You can extract a 4-quadrant detector from just about any old cd-rom drive (they need them to stay in focus with their astigmatic lensing system.) Pinhole to 4-quadrant detector determines the field of view (FOV.) Sun image and light intensity depend on the diameter of the pinhole. For example, at \$L=42\:\text{mm}\$ and a pinhole diameter of \$800\:\mu\text{m}\$ and 4-quad w/\$5\:\text{mm}\$ sides implies FOV of \$7^\circ\$. Pinhole optics is pretty simple, really. I also like Kate's solution. I've a book that gives all the formulas you'd need for that, too.

Comment: Tim, the point here is that you need to have a background in a variety of techniques so that you can choose the one that better suits your specific situation. I actually think that, ignorant of other science theory, the idea of just plugging in your latitude and working out equations of sunrise and sunset and the arc across your sky is probably a ***lot*** easier than making detector systems to do similar things for you. Formulas are easy and don't require any science knowledge on your part. The disadvantage is that your code is specific to your location. 1ate's idea is the easy answer.

Comment: Explain how ‘one will become shaded’.

Comment: Add a schematic of your circuit.

Comment: your voltmeter is a much smaller load (~10M) than an ESP's ADC (~100K); the ADC pulls down the voltage since the LED makes next to no current.

Comment: Sounds like you followed a youtube video in which one might believe that sun may change his position arbitrarily and in very short amount of time. In fact it's quite similar every day. Sun rises east and sets west. As long as you don't carry it into a different place every day, a fixed procedure should be fine.

Comment: @ThomasWeller True, but two simple light sensors plus appropriate SW filtering are certainly cheaper and easier to set up than an RTC clock stable over many years (or a GPS module).

Comment: @jsotola The LEDs are green but not in any housing. I have considered using tiny solar panels and may still do that since the LEDs may not be generating enough power for the ADC.

Comment: @Sim Son I had not considered photodiodes. Do they last under continuous exposure to the sun or turn cloudy and fail like photoresistors?

Comment: @jonk I should have stated that this is on an RV so calculating the position of the sun is not an option since the panels are always on the move.

Comment: @Chu The LEDs are mounted a few inches below the panel on each side. As the sun moves, one of the LEDs naturally becomes shaded.

Comment: @HandyHowie Mattman944 did it for me below. LOL

Comment: @dandavis Now this is helpful information! Thank you!

Comment: @TimDuncklee Hmm. Then the pinhole idea isn't necessarily wrong and the software idea is necessarily wrong. Thanks. But the RV info was critical and should have been in the question, early on. Thanks for the note.

Comment: @SimSon: An LED does work in reverse as an inefficient light->electricity transducer, with light driving the photovoltaic process.  It just won't be very optimized for that, but optical reflection is symmetric so an LED designed so that photons emitted in the junction can escape will by definition have a path for photons from outside to get to the junction, and the sun is pretty bright.  Although not all paths in must lead to the jct.  (A layer of phosphor material in a blue -> white diode might make this even worse, so maybe a simple red or green LED is better for this, or at least as good.)

Comment: What's the bias current on the ADC inputs? That could be messing you up. You may need a FET input buffer (very low input bias current) between the sensor and the ADC input.

Comment: I wouldn't use LEDs for that at all. Photodiodes (PDs) are optimized to convert photons to current, LEDs are not. PDs can probably deal much better with UV than photoresistors, just like LEDs I'd say. Probably the most suitable component for your approach is a phototransistor: it has high gain and can be arranged in a simple voltage divider to get a strong signal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your setup should work if the ADC input impedance is high enough.

I assume that you are using the LED in photovoltaic mode as shown below. The output of the LED will be weak, the ADC input impedance will need to be about 1 Mohm or higher. I just tried a 100k load and the voltage was significantly less, with a 1 M load the voltage output is almost the same.

To troubleshoot, you need to try something simpler. Connect a voltage source instead and see what happens. Use a power supply set to 1V or one AA battery.

If your setup can read a stiff voltage input, then put a 100k resistor in series. If it changes considerably, you have found the problem.

You may need to ask a simpler question, such as: "why can't my ESP32 read a voltage with a 100k series resistor". Then people won't be distracted with your solar system choices. The comments are useful, but aren't addressing your problem.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhL4SZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I personally think that your system design isn't too bad. No it won't work on cloudy days, but your photocells won't produce much on these days anyway. You could have your motor set the angle to south if the voltages on both your sensors are low. You seem to be more comfortable with software, you can handle this once your sensors are working.

Comment: Why point North?

Comment: Fixed, south is optimum for fixed installations (or lacking good data).

Comment: I guess it depends which hemisphere you are on.  It looks like the OP is only just in the northern hemisphere.

Comment: @Mattman944 By far the best answer. Thank you so much! I'm doing exactly as you say now. :)

Answer (score 16):

This has to be the worst way to go about it.  Several reasons: Cloudy days where both get equal light; In the morning, neither is getting any light.  I've seen this done your way as a college project and it didn't work out for those reasons.

Try using a look-up table that knows where the sun will be for your latitude and day of the year.  Tie it into a feedback loop that can position the panel according to that data.

Comment: Agreed. Far better solution. No sunlight sensors required do no concern with sensors going bad in direct sunlight.

Comment: And setting the time with NTP would at least justify using a power-hungry micro instead of a µA comparator...

Comment: @bobflux A microcontroller could do this and would be asleep most of the time and while asleep would use µA.

Comment: While you can do away with sunlight sensors this way, you have to replace them with an encoder to track the current position of the panel. Also, if both sensors get equal light due to clouds, it also means the panel will work the same no matter which way it points, so it might as well stay in the current position.

Comment: @Kate Moon I should have mentioned that this is no an RV so look-up tables are a non-starter for me.

Comment: @TimDuncklee you could have a microcontroller with a compass so it knows the direction the RV is facing.  It would still be the best option.

Comment: @HandyHowie The microcontroller would also need a GPS to know where in North America I'm at. I'd also need to add an angle sensor to the pannels to know what angle they are at. Going this route is not looking all that good to me. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: @TimDuncklee A GPS module is $15 or less, and it opens up all kinds of possibilities for other applications in your ESP32. A compass with 3-axis accelerometer and magnetometer is $10 or less.  Your panels will need motors with encoders anyway because you'll want the micro to actually be able to confirm that the panels went where they're supposed to and to notify you if there's a positioning fault, presumably.

Comment: @TimDuncklee You said you were only doing single axis tracking in your question, so why would you need a GPS and angle sensor?

Comment: Just be aware that esp32 ADC have bad reputations. Especially at low voltage read.

Comment: @netmonk Indeed - a good strategy for the ESP is to bias the analog signal into the middle of the range (where the ADC is more linear) and then to restrict the range to avoid the gnarly ends.  This tends to work quite well.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the side conversation between *jonk* and *J...* has been [moved to this chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124682/discussion-on-answer-by-kate-moon-using-leds-to-track-the-sun-with-esp32-analog) and must remain there. Any further posting about that here as *comments*, may be deleted without notice. Please *keep it in chat*. Thanks.

Comment: +1. I built this very thing back in high school using LEDs, comparators and relays to drive the motors to rotate the solar panel. Clouds were a problem and I ended up staying in my project report that a LUT was the way forward since you don’t need to mess with feedback if you already can compute the answer.